# rebar generate: enotdir errors

Tags: erlang, rebar

I am trying to setup a rebar release for my otp application. I followed this guide: https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki/Getting-started

When I try to generate a release, I get lots of enotdir errors:

```
~/Projekte/mc-erl/repo $ ./rebar generate
==> rel (generate)
Error reading /home/clonejo/Projekte/mc-erl/repo/rebar/rebar_app_utils.beam's file info: enotdir
Error reading /home/clonejo/Projekte/mc-erl/repo/rebar/rebar_deps.beam's file info: enotdir
Error reading /home/clonejo/Projekte/mc-erl/repo/rebar/rebar_appups.beam's file info: enotdir
[... enotdir errors go on ...]
[... all above enotdir errors are repeated ...]
ERROR: Unable to generate spec: read file info /usr/lib/erlang/man/man1/preunzip.1 failed
```

This is my version of erlang:

```
$ erl
Erlang R15B (erts-5.9) [source] [64-bit] [smp:2:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.9  (abort with ^G)
```

I got rebar at http://cloud.github.com/downloads/basho/rebar/rebar (see the GettingStarted wiki page).

**Update:** Verbose mode only adds one warning, which is unrelated:

```
WARN:  'generate' command does not apply to directory /home/clonejo/Projekte/mc-erl/repo/apps/mc_erl
```

Comment: Could you run rebar in verbose (-v) mode and show us the log?

Comment: verbose mode only adds one warning, which is unrelated (see above)

Comment: Can I suggest you to build from source?

Comment: I did, but there is no change in the output (commit: afffb48)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you have installed the "reloader" module somehow, perhaps via your .erlang?  That specific error message originates from there.

Answer (score 1):

Could you run it with -v

There was and maybe still is  a bug
http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/rebar_lists.basho.com/2011-July/000932.html

I would suggest to update rebar and run rebar -v to see more info.

Comment: No difference when using an up-to-date version of rebar:


`rebar version: 2 date: 20120417_234834 vcs: git afffb48`